# Convert String to Char* and Hash It using SHA-256

Tags: arduino, sha256, esp32, arduino-c++

I'm trying to concatenate the current `DateTime` to my devices Mac Address in the following format: `aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ffYYmmDDhhMMss` so I can hash it and send it to a web service every time I collect new data (so I'll have to hash it in every loop)

I managed to concatenate the two values (mac address + datetime) and converted it to `char` array

```
addressDateTime.toCharArray(thisThing, 28);
```

However, I'm kind of lost as to how to continue.

I've also tried to read the resulting `char*` with this cycle but I'm not understanding why it doesn't work:

```
void loop() {
  while (!timeClient.update()) {
    timeClient.forceUpdate();
  }
  String addressDateTime = getPayload(); //this gets the *aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ffYYmmDDhhMMss* string
  char* hashThis;
  addressDateTime.toCharArray(hashThis, 28);

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(hashThis); i++) {
    char str[3];
    sprintf(str, "%02x", hashThis[i]);
    Serial.print(str);
  }
  delay(5000);
}
```

Am I converting the `String` to `char*` correctly?

How should I go about Hashing the `char*`?

Or can I Hash the String without converting it to to `char*`?

#### Update:

My code's looking like this atm

```
  while (!timeClient.update()) {
    timeClient.forceUpdate();
  }
  String addressDateTime = getPayload();
  char hashThis[30];
  addressDateTime.toCharArray(hashThis, 30);

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(hashThis); i++) {
    Serial.printf("%02x", hashThis[i]);
  }
  delay(5000);
}
```

So I managed to convert the `String` to `Char*` Except that the output is looking like this `33433a37313a42463a31443a34323a463431393035303531343038323700` instead of (for example) `aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff190505141037`

After figuring out why my `char*` array outputs like that I still have to hash it.

Thanks for helping me get this far, I still have ways to go

Comment: Are you sure this is C? What is `String`?

Comment: @mnistic Oh, edited that tag out, I was under the impression Arduino IDE language was C

Comment: It's C++, so a superset of C. @mnistic, String is an Arduino Core class.

Answer (score 1):

You're not allocating space to store the C string that you're getting from `addressDateTime`.

`hashThis` is a `char*` which is a pointer to a character. It hasn't been set to anything so it's just... random. Which will almost certainly make your program crash or at least misbehave badly.

Given your code, the quickest fix is to change

```
    char* hashThis;
```

to

```
    char hasThis[30];
    addressDateTime.toCharArray(hashThis, 30);
```

I changed 28 to 30 because `aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ffYYmmDDhhMMss` is actually 29 characters long and also requires an extra byte for the C string null terminator character. I'm not 100% sure if the `toCharArray()` method sets the null terminator; if it doesn't, you'd need to add

```
    hasThis[29] = '\0';
```

You can avoid that by just using the String `c_str()` method, which returns a `char*` to the internal buffer that String uses to hold the string.

In that case you could rewrite

```
    char* hashThis;
    addressDateTime.toCharArray(hashThis, 28);
```

as

```
    char* hashThis = addressDateTime.c_str();
```

By the way, you can also just do

```
    Serial.printf("%02x", hashThis[i]);
```

and dispense with the `snprintf()`. Kudos on getting the right buffer size there, though!

**UPDATE**

In your updated question, you said that you're expecting to see output that looks like:

```
aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff190505141037
```

instead of:

```
33433a37313a42463a31443a34323a463431393035303531343038323700
```

Your code is

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(hashThis); i++) {
  Serial.printf("%02x", hashThis[i]);
}
```

You're writing each character as a two digit hexadecimal number, so you're going to see the number in hexadecimal that represents the character, not the character itself. If you want to see the characters, do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(hashThis); i++) {
  Serial.printf("%c", hashThis[i]);
}
```

or (better)

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(hashThis); i++) {
  Serial.print(hashThis[i]);
}
```

or (best)

```
Serial.println(hashThis);
```

Note that I changed your `sizeof` to a `strlen`. If for some reason you put a shorter string in `hashThis`, `strlen` will do the right thing whereas `sizeof` will always return the length that `hashThis` was declared with rather than the length of the string in it.

Comment: Thanks! I followed suit and managed to concatenate the strings, convert them to a char array and read them, although i'm puzzled by what the console is printing, which is 60 characters long line of mostly numbers and a couple of letters "a" scattered.
at the end of array I can see the seconds and minutes updating, but i also get two 0's at the very end of the line

maybe i'm missing the snprintf() function you mentioned, i don't think i understand how i'm supposed to use it

Comment: If you update your question by adding your current code to the end (please leave the original question in place and just add an update), I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I've answered your additional question.